# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__' running the executable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyinstaller

I have created a script that works fine through Python, then I created an executable and I obtain the error:

```
File "site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

All the other questions I found are related to scripts running through Python.

It seems to be a `import` problem but I don't know how to solve it in the executable.

This is my `.spec` file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Projects\\Test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['numpy', 'pandas', 'pandas.compat', 'xml', 'xml.etree', 'xml.etree.ElementTree'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=['.\\pyi_rth_arcpy.py'],
             excludes=['arcpy'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
          cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='test')
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

To use the module `arcpy` I created the `runtime_hook` named `pyi_rth_arcpy.py` (I copied from another question).
In this script I added a fake `site-packages` and `numpy` module to `sys.path` and this created the `import` problem.

I just changed, into `pyi_rth_arcpy.py`, `numpy` to a module that I don't use, I chose `scipy`.

This is `pyi_rth_arcpy.py`:

```
import sys

# Add arcpy's directories to sys.path
from archook import get_arcpy
get_arcpy()

# Additional tweaks to placate arcpy
from types import ModuleType
sys.path.append('./site-packages')  # Add a dummy site-packages folder to sys.path
sys.modules['scipy'] = ModuleType('scipy')  # Add a fake scipy module to sys.modules
```